# About described DFA

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I need to find DFA (or NFA, $\epsilon$-NFA, it's not improtant (I know how to convert between them)) that accept all strings of $0$'s and $1$'s such that every block of five consecutive symbols contains at least two $0$'s.

This is exercise 2.5 c) from Hopcroft's Introduction to Automata Theory.

If someone could also explain and help to build regular expresion from this (I'm still learning)?

Comment: Going from DFA to regex is tedious mechanical work. Just follow the recipe in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try the opposite: find DFA that accepts all strings of 0's and 1's such that there exists a block of five consecutive symbols containing one or zero 0's. And then build the complement to this DFA.

**Added:** There was a typo: "every block" -> "*there exists* a block". Sorry.

Comment: Great hint, we didn't even study about complement and I see it's helpful but I'm even stuck with this :/

Comment: @Mare: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer, i've corrected it.

Comment: =) Thank you. So far I think that your DFA has regex (11111+01111)(1+01111)*, but transforming that to DFA would have too much states. =D I need to study more